# Consultar si registro existe en BD Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, nodejs, angular, oracle, typescript

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta con NodeJS en una base de datos Oracle SQL

```
export async function getGuard(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
    const conn = await connect();
    let { documento} = req.params;
    const result = await conn.execute(
        `
      select ideide 
      from basdat.siide, basdat.siideead
      where idecod='${documento}'
      and idecod=ideeadcod
      and ideeadact='S'
      `

    );
    console.log(result.rows[0][0].length);
    if (result.rows[0][0].length > 0) {
        return res.json(result.rows[0][0]);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ text: "Registro no existe" });
    }
}
```

Y estoy tratantdo de validar que si ese registro que le estoy enviando no existe pueda generar una accion en un formulario de Registro en Angular

```
    this.documentoreg = this.forma.value.documento
    console.log(this.documentoreg);
    this._usuarioService.getdocumento(this.forma.value.documento)
      .subscribe( resp => { 
        this.documentoser = resp;
        console.log('documentode usuario servinte',resp)
        if (this.documentoreg == this.documentoser) {
          console.log('si son iguales');

        } else {
          console.log('No son iguales');

        }
      }, err => {
           console.log(err);
      }


    );
```

Cuando el registro existe me ejecuta el IF pero cuando le paso un documento que no existe no me esta devolviendo nada, ni siquiera ejecuta el IF

PD: La base de datos de Oracle solo la utilizo para consultar si el documento existe, no estoy almacenando nada en ella

Comment: Si devolves un 404 no es un error? en realidad deberias siempre devolver un 200 (porque se ejecuto bien) y dentro de la respuesta, aclarar que es lo que pasa.

Comment: @gbianchi Es cuestíón de opiniones, un HTTP Status 404 (Not found) se usa para indicar que el recurso pedido no existe. En un API RESTful es [correcto](https://swapi.co/api/people/100/)

Comment: Si @PabloLozano .. pero el recurso existe.. hay un endpoint correcto.. y lo esta mandando como error, entonces no va a poder dicernir entre, no encontre el endpoint de la api, o lo encontre, ejecute y el registro existia...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veo un par de detalles en la forma en la que estás trabajando en la parte del lado servidor.

En primer lugar, tienes una función tipo `async`. En la misma usas la palabra `await` para realizar la conexión y para ejecutar la consulta.

Si estás usando [`node-oracledb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) (no lo especificas, pero imagino que sí), debes envolver tu código dentro de un bloque `try/catch`. Ya que al no hacerlo no estarías capturando un posible error de conexión o un error en la consulta.

Al ser un servicio REST, dichos errores deben ser indicados al cliente usando un estado `HTTP 5xx`, ya que los mismos son errores de Servidor. El mensaje que envíes al cliente depende lo que desees exponer de tu API. Te recomiendo mensajes personalizados si tu API es pública, ya que el `driver` de Oracle podría mostrar detalles de tu esquema de Base de Datos si envías directamente el mensaje al cliente.

En segundo lugar, como indica @PabloLozano, si la respuesta enviada al cliente incluye un estado `404`, entonces el cliente no recibirá una respuesta válida (HTTP 2xx) por parte de tu API.

Una forma de solventar esto, si deseas mantener el estado `404` para indicar un recurso no encontrado (cosa que no es exactamente lo que sucede), es usar un interceptor, tal como sugiere @PabloLozano.

Otra forma de hacerlo, sería no enviar el estado `404` al cliente cuando la consulta no arroja resultados. En vez de eso envías una respuesta al cliente (por lo general un objeto vacío o un `array` vacío), y que sea el cliente el que interprete el resultado obtenido.

Como en tu cliente ya estás probando o comparando objetos, entonces lo ideal sería enviar un objeto vacío.

Tu código del lado servidor podría quedar así:

```js
export async function getGuard(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
  try {
    const conn = await connect();
    let { documento} = req.params;
    const result = await conn.execute(
      `
      select ideide 
      from basdat.siide, basdat.siideead
      where idecod='${documento}'
      and idecod=ideeadcod
      and ideeadact='S'
      `
    );
    console.log(result.rows[0][0].length);
    // verificamos si NO tenemos resultados de la consulta
    if(!result.rows[0][0].length) {
      // devolvemos un objeto vacío al cliente
      return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    // si tenemos resultado, enviamos el mismo
    return res.status(200).json(result.rows[0][0]);
  }
  // capturamos la excepción ya sea de conexión o de la consulta
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    // enviamos un mensaje personalizado al cliente
    return res.status(500).json({error: 'Hubo un problema al realizar la consulta'});
    // en caso de que deseemos enviar el mensaje de error devuelto por el driver:
    // return res.status(500).json({error: e.message});
    // no olvidemos comentar el return anterior si usamos este último.
  }
}
```

De esta forma, cuando recibas una respuesta en tu cliente, tendrás control sobre el resultado de la consulta que recibas, teniendo los siguiente casos:

1. Error de servidor mostrado mediante un estado `HTTP 500`.
2. Respuesta del Servidor mediante un estado `HTTP 200`, la cual incluye:

   - Documento/Registro encontrado en la consulta y devuelto por el Servidor.

Obviamente, si la consulta no devuelve resultados (o devuelve un `objeto/array` vacío), significa que el registro no ha sido encontrado en la Base de Datos.

De esta forma separas tus estados tipo `404` que normalmente se refieren a un recurso de red no encontrado, de los errores tipo `500` que son los que suceden cuando el Servidor tiene un fallo interno (no se pudo conectar a la BD o la consulta a la DB devolvió un error).

Si la conexión y consulta a la BD (proceso interno de tu servidor) son satisfactorias, entonces no es necesario devolver un estado diferente del `200`, ya que:

1. El recurso (`endpoint`) es accesible.
2. La operación de dicho recurso fue satisfactoria.

Espero que esto aclare un poco más tus dudas.

Comment: Gracias Por la respuesta, fue muy util

Answer (score 2):

Si la respuesta tiene un status 404, se considera un error y no se ejecutará la función que se le pasa a subscribe, sino que necesitarás capturarla con `catchError`, algo como :

```
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...

getDocumento(docId) {
  return this.httpClient.get<Documento>(url + docId, opciones).pipe(
    catchError(this.errorHandler);
}

errorHandler(error) {
  console.log('Ocurrió un error', error.status);
  return of.(null);
}
```

Aunque podrías tener un interceptor global que se encargue en toda la aplicación de capturar todos los errores [HTTP de manera centralizada](https://blog.angularindepth.com/expecting-the-unexpected-best-practices-for-error-handling-in-angular-21c3662ef9e4), para no tener que repetir este código en cada servicio.